# Visual C# command Line compiler has stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have couple of projects, before last night all projects were running very well but now when I execute my last built project I am getting error which is title of my question

And the message was displayed.!

The problem signature reads the following:
 Problem signature:

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH

  Application Name: Csc.exe

  Application Version:  12.0.31101.0

  Application Timestamp:    54545d10

  Fault Module Name:    Csc.exe

  Fault Module Version: 12.0.31101.0

  Fault Module Timestamp:   54545d10
  Exception Code:   c000001d

  Exception Offset: 000c1e64

  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1

  Locale ID:    1033

  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I need to resolve this quickly:
Command Line Compiler stops working in specific project.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Did you or admin make any changes or updates on a) OS, b) C++ compiler c) your project?

Comment: No ..i have a full rights on my projects